# Logic to determine whether a "prompt" should be printed out

Tags: c, shell, fork, background-process

Seems like a basic idea: I want to print out a prompt for a mini shell I am making in C. Here is an example of what I mean for the prompt:

`$ ls`

The `$` being the "prompt". This little mini shell I am making supports backgrounding a process via the normal bash notation of putting a `&` symbol on the end of a line. Like `$ ls &`.

My logic currently is that in my main command loop, if the process is not going to be backgrounded then print out the prompt:

```
if(isBackground == 0)
    prompt();
```

And then in my signal handler I print out the prompt using `write()` which covers the case of it being a background process.

This works fine if the background command returns right away like with a quick `$ ls &`, but in the case of something like `$ sleep 10 &` the shell will look like it is being blocked as the prompt will not be printed out until it hits the signal handler.

I can't figure out how to fix this because I don't know when the background process will end which means that the signal handler somehow needs to be saying when to print the new prompt because if the background process happened to have an output, it would output and then there would no longer be a prompt.

How can I resolve this problem? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of that could resolve my problem?

Comment: How are you running the process? If it is not backgrounded, wait for it before continuing to the REPL, if not, just continue. You shouldn't have to check if it is backgrounded or not.

Comment: @muru if it is not backgrounded then a normal `fork` happens where the child will be replaced via `execvp` and ran and the parent will `waitpid` for it to be done. This one works fine and does not relate to the background one. When backgrounded however I am using a `signal` with a signal handler. This is where the problem with the prompt comes in.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using your signal handler to write the prompt. I think your design is a bit weird, then. The signal handler should probably set a flag or something that that the main loop can check. I don't see why it should be messing with the prompt (other information, yes; prompt, no).

Comment: @muru but if there is a flag that is set, when is the main program going to be checking that? There is a loop that is executed on every command entered. If the background process terminates in the middle of waiting for the users command then the background processes stdout will be outputted and there will be no prompt anymore as it already was previously outputted in order to wait for the next command while the other process runs in the background. I hope this clears up the issue?

Comment: Not really. That is what happens on shells that I commonly use: bash, zsh, dash. Background programs' output comes in independently of what's going on in the main shell. So, if a prompt was printed, it gets drowned out in output.

Comment: I agree with @muru. Your design sounds entirely wrong or strange at best. It seems you are doing it backwards compared to how all other shells operate. If the command is run as a background process then just print the prompt immediately after forking off the child process. If it is not a background process then `wait` for the child to exit before printing the prompt.

Comment: @muru here is the problem with printing it immediately: http://pastebin.com/7g4Qx5E7 My shell is the one with only the `$`, my normal zsh shell is the fancier one showing how it reacts. See the problems? This is when I do it the way you are suggesting.

Comment: @kaylum see my previous comment for the problem with that way.

Comment: @Fogest that suggests something is causing your zsh prompt to be printed very slowly. This is what I get: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15066432/

Comment: Well it doesn't mean what we have suggested is wrong. It suggests to me some other problem in your code. Namely you do not seem to be collecting the exit status of each child process. Your question is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to solve a particular problem but instead of asking about that problem you are asking about what you have decided (arguably incorrectly) is the solution (signals).

Comment: @muru okay I guess I will leave it like that then!

Comment: @kaylum I disagree. My problem is that my zsh shell has been printing them a different way than what it appears most shells like what muru showed would be printing them so I was under the assumption that that is how my shell should be reacting, when really it appear my zsh shell may just have some weird delay happening.

Comment: @Fogest Ok, as long as your problem is solved to your satisfaction.

Comment: @kaylum from my understanding it sounds like this may just be the way it works and there is no real easy way to solve this.

Comment: Well, it's hard to see exactly the timing of what you did by just looking at the output you provided. In your shell it doesn't tell us when the child exits (that may be something you are implementing later). In the `zsh` case it is not clear why you did not run the `ls&` in the second `A1` prompt but waited until the first child exits (it may have been that the shell didn't allow you..but can't tell that from the output).

Comment: @kaylum when the `&`'s are present child exits after program finishes. `SIGCHLD`. That is why in my output you see that the `ls` output is on the same line as the prompt as the parent process will finish its loop before and print out the prompt again before the ls command finishes and dumps out its output. In the zsh case you can see the order happened differently. It would appear that the ls program finished first, outputted, and then the zsh prompt appeared.

Comment: @kaylum if it helps here is an output of these commands in my shell where I added in some print statements for when the fork is made and for when the child is done: http://pastebin.com/JcHkBNkF